# Configured APEX Rest Data Source, Unable to POST data using it

Tags: oracle, apex, 400-bad-request, restdatasource

I have configured a Rest Data Source to in APEX and created form using it. When I'm trying to create item/dept(input values giving from form), I could not able to do it. I got error: ORA-20999: REST Data Source returned an HTTP error: HTTP 400: Bad request

[forms link](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/configured-apex-rest-data-source-unable-to-post-data-using-1750)

I have posted same issue in forms and I'm sharing its link. Please, let me know if anyone know how to resolve it

[text](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/configured-apex-rest-data-source-unable-to-post-data-using-1750)

I have posted same issue in forms and I'm sharing its link. Please, let me know if anyone know how to resolve it